# How do I represent square brackets ([]) in RDoc?

Tags: ruby, rdoc

I am trying to document some rake tasks I've written using RDoc comments in my class and am running into trouble representing square brackets.  I want to add some examples of how to run my rake tasks with parameters and so have an rdoc line like so:

# eg. `rake build[MyProject]`

The problem is that the RDoc parser convert creates a link instead of printing the square brackets.  I have tried all sorts of escape sequences: [ ; [[ ; #{[MyProject]} ; &#91;MyProject&#93; but nothing seems to work.

Is there any way to escape these square brackets so they don't convert to a link?

Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well with further experimentation I discovered a way to do it.  If I put two spaces in front of each line, RDoc treats the line as pre formatted text and renders the brackets.  Good enough for me.

The resulting RDoc line is:

```
#  eg. rake build[MyProject]
```

Comment: Indenting is correct since you are showing a coding sample. It should be indented and display in a fixed-width font since that is the accepted convention.

Comment: Go ahead and accept your answer to this question. That way it will show as having been answered in SO's interface.

Answer (score 2):

The `<tt>` tag will escape the link-text[hyperlink] syntax (and also put the text in a monospace font).

So this rdoc

```
# eg. <tt>rake build[MyProject]</tt>
```

will produce this documentation:

eg. `rake build[MyProject]`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the solution is easy.

Code like `text[par]` creates *text* with a link to par. But if you put a space between `text` and `[par]` you get *par* with square brackets.

A short overview of different versions with []:

```
* [par] labeled list
* x[par] x is linked with par
* x [par] Text as is (space between x and par)
* []  brackets disapear
* x _[par]_  Content between[] disapears.
```

If you want to make the text with the `text<space>[par]`-solution in italic, you must use the `<em>...</em>` variant (not the underscore variant `_..._`).